# Asynchronous UDFs and xleventCalculationCanceled

Tags: xll

As soon as I press "Enter" after I wrote an asynchronous function into a cell, the async function is correctly called, and Excel raises the event `xleventCalculationEnded` when the calculation is finished.

However, if I press another cell just after I clicked "Enter" , the event `xleventCalculationCanceled` is raised, and then the async function is called another time ! Is this behavior normal ? Should I return a result via the `Excel12(xlAsyncReturn,...)`  for the first async call , for the second async call or for both ?

In other word, does the `xleventCalculationCanceled` event implies that **I'm not** forced to return a result to Excel ? (using the appropriate `asyncHandle`)

I'm using async functions to delegate intensive computation in another thread and to not block excel during computation. However if the async function is called automatically two times (as it is the case when the user click another cell without waiting for the first call to finish) then the intensive computation are computed two times for the same input (because the first call -cancelled by excel- still live in the delegate thread...) How do you deal with this problem ?

Two calls for the same function - with the same input - is it a bug ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the normal behaviour. Excel cancels and then restarts the async calculations when there is user interaction (and can do so multiple times).

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff475876.aspx) suggest that:

1. `xleventCalculationEnded` will fire directly after `xleventCalculationCanceled`, and
2. You can release any resources allocated during the calculation when `xleventCalculationEnded` fires. I understand that to include any `asyncHandle` you might have, and thus that you need not return any result based on the handle.

If your long-running function allows cancellation while in flight, you can cancel the work you do. Otherwise, you might do some internal bookkeeping on what function calls are in flight, and prevent doing the work twice yourself that way.